# TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

I am new to python and TensorFlow. I recently started understanding and executing TensorFlow examples, and came across this one: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/wide_and_deep/index.html

I got the error, **TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable**, and I believe that the problem is with the following line of code:

```
df_train[LABEL_COLUMN] = (df_train['income_bracket'].apply(lambda x: '>50K' in x)).astype(int)
```

(income_bracket is the label column of the census dataset, with '>50K' being one of the possible label values, and the other label is '=<50K'. The dataset is read into df_train. The explanation provided in the documentation for the reason to do the above is, "Since the task is a binary classification problem, we'll construct a label column named "label" whose value is 1 if the income is over 50K, and 0 otherwise.")

If anyone could explain me what is exactly happening and how should I fix it, that'll be great. I tried using Python2.7 and Python3.4, and I don't think that the problem is with the version of the language. Also, if anyone is aware of great tutorials for someone who is new to TensorFlow and pandas, please share the links.

Complete program:

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib
import tempfile
import tensorflow as tf

gender = tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_keys(column_name="gender", keys=["female", "male"])
race = tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_keys(column_name="race", keys=["Amer-Indian-Eskimo", "Asian-Pac-Islander", "Black", "Other", "White"])
education = tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_hash_bucket("education", hash_bucket_size=1000)
marital_status = tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_hash_bucket("marital_status", hash_bucket_size=100)
relationship = tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_hash_bucket("relationship", hash_bucket_size=100)
workclass = tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_hash_bucket("workclass", hash_bucket_size=100)
occupation = tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_hash_bucket("occupation", hash_bucket_size=1000)
native_country = tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_hash_bucket("native_country", hash_bucket_size=1000)


age = tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("age")
age_buckets = tf.contrib.layers.bucketized_column(age, boundaries=[18, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65])
education_num = tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("education_num")
capital_gain = tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("capital_gain")
capital_loss = tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("capital_loss")
hours_per_week = tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("hours_per_week")

wide_columns = [gender, native_country, education, occupation, workclass, marital_status, relationship, age_buckets, tf.contrib.layers.crossed_column([education, occupation], hash_bucket_size=int(1e4)), tf.contrib.layers.crossed_column([native_country, occupation], hash_bucket_size=int(1e4)), tf.contrib.layers.crossed_column([age_buckets, race, occupation], hash_bucket_size=int(1e6))]

deep_columns = [
  tf.contrib.layers.embedding_column(workclass, dimension=8),
  tf.contrib.layers.embedding_column(education, dimension=8),
  tf.contrib.layers.embedding_column(marital_status, dimension=8),
  tf.contrib.layers.embedding_column(gender, dimension=8),
  tf.contrib.layers.embedding_column(relationship, dimension=8),
  tf.contrib.layers.embedding_column(race, dimension=8),
  tf.contrib.layers.embedding_column(native_country, dimension=8),
  tf.contrib.layers.embedding_column(occupation, dimension=8),
  age, education_num, capital_gain, capital_loss, hours_per_week]

model_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
m = tf.contrib.learn.DNNLinearCombinedClassifier(
    model_dir=model_dir,
    linear_feature_columns=wide_columns,
    dnn_feature_columns=deep_columns,
    dnn_hidden_units=[100, 50])


COLUMNS = ["age", "workclass", "fnlwgt", "education", "education_num",
  "marital_status", "occupation", "relationship", "race", "gender",
  "capital_gain", "capital_loss", "hours_per_week", "native_country", "income_bracket"]
LABEL_COLUMN = 'label'
CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS = ["workclass", "education", "marital_status", "occupation", "relationship", "race", "gender", "native_country"]
CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS = ["age", "education_num", "capital_gain", "capital_loss", "hours_per_week"]


train_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
test_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
urllib.urlretrieve("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data", train_file.name)
urllib.urlretrieve("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.test", test_file.name)


df_train = pd.read_csv(train_file, names=COLUMNS, skipinitialspace=True)
df_test = pd.read_csv(test_file, names=COLUMNS, skipinitialspace=True, skiprows=1)
df_train[LABEL_COLUMN] = (df_train['income_bracket'].apply(lambda x: '>50K' in x)).astype(int)
df_test[LABEL_COLUMN] = (df_test['income_bracket'].apply(lambda x: '>50K' in x)).astype(int)


def input_fn(df):

  continuous_cols = {k: tf.constant(df[k].values)
                     for k in CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS}

  categorical_cols = {k: tf.SparseTensor(
      indices=[[i, 0] for i in range(df[k].size)],
      values=df[k].values,
      shape=[df[k].size, 1])
                      for k in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS}

  feature_cols = dict(continuous_cols.items() + categorical_cols.items())
  label = tf.constant(df[LABEL_COLUMN].values)
  return feature_cols, label


def train_input_fn():
    return input_fn(df_train)


def eval_input_fn():
    return input_fn(df_test)

m.fit(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=200)
results = m.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn, steps=1)
for key in sorted(results):
    print("%s: %s" % (key, results[key]))
```

Thank you

PS: Full stack trace for the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  
File "/home/jaspreet/PycharmProjects/TicTacTensorFlow/census.py", line 73, in <module>
    df_train[LABEL_COLUMN] = (df_train['income_bracket'].apply(lambda x: '>50K' in x)).astype(int)
  
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2023, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
 
File "inference.pyx", line 920, in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas/lib.c:44780)
  
File "/home/jaspreet/PycharmProjects/TicTacTensorFlow/census.py", line 73, in <lambda>
    df_train[LABEL_COLUMN] = (df_train['income_bracket'].apply(lambda x: '>50K' in x)).astype(int)

TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace for the error?

Comment: I just updated the question with the full stack trace @mrry

Comment: It looks like `pandas` has parsed your "income_bracket" field as a `float`, rather than a string. Can you try adding `print df_train['income_bracket'].dtype` to your code and let us know the result?

Comment: @mrry result : object

Comment: Are you trying to filter out that string from the dataframe? If so, I don't think `apply` is the method you want. Otherwise, the binary classification is returning True/False, not 0 and 1

Comment: This code works for me verbatim (using pandas 0.18.1). Are you perhaps using an old version of pandas?

Comment: There are probably NaNs in that Series. You can use [str.contains](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) which would handle NaNs as well, or use `fillna()` before applying that function.

Comment: @mrry I checked, I am also using pandas 0.18.1. Thanks for letting me know that it works for you. It didn't work for a friend either, so I was wondering if there's a problem in the program itself. I'll reinstall pandas

Comment: @ayhan, okay, I'll try that. Thanks

Comment: @mrry, I reinstalled pandas and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program works verbatim with the latest version of pandas, i.e., 0.18.1

Answer (score 9):

As you can see, when you inspect the `test.data`, you will obviously see that the first line of data has "NAN" in `income_bracket` field.

I have further inspected that this is the only line contains "NAN" by doing:

```
ib = df_test ["income_bracket"]
t = type('12')
for idx,i in enumerate(ib):
    if(type(i) != t):
        print idx,type(i)
```

`RESULT: 0 <type 'float'>`

So you may just skip this row by:

`df_test  = pd.read_csv(file_test , names=COLUMNS, skipinitialspace=True, skiprows=1)`

Answer (score 0):

maybe got a number in the for loop after in keyword
try to skip it with a test ("isinstance" )

```
if(isinstance(lines, str)):
   for x in lines:
       foo()
else:
   skip
```