# TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable-Tensorflow wide_n_deep_tutorial

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

I am facing an issue while running the wide_n_deep_tutorial program of TensorFlow https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/wide_n_deep_tutorial.py on my personal data set with variation is the parameters. I am loading my data from S3.

My target variable is "impression_flag" which the takes the value of either "TRUE" or "FALSE". Below is the code snippet of the train_and_eval method:

```
    def train_and_eval():
  """Train and evaluate the model."""
  train_file_name, test_file_name = maybe_download()
  df_train = pd.read_csv(
      tf.gfile.Open(train_file_name),
      names=COLUMNS,
      skipinitialspace=True)
  df_test = pd.read_csv(
      tf.gfile.Open(test_file_name),
      names=COLUMNS,
      skipinitialspace=True,
      skiprows=1)
  df_train[LABEL_COLUMN] = (
      df_train["impression_flag"].apply(lambda x: "TRUE" in x)).astype(int)
  df_test[LABEL_COLUMN] = (
      df_test["impression_flag"].apply(lambda x: "TRUE" in x)).astype(int)

  model_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp() if not FLAGS.model_dir else FLAGS.model_dir
  print("model directory = %s" % model_dir)

  m = build_estimator(model_dir)
  m.fit(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_train), steps=FLAGS.train_steps)
  results = m.evaluate(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_test), steps=1)
  for key in sorted(results):
    print("%s: %s" % (key, results[key]))
```

While running the code, an error "Type Error: argument of type 'float' is not iterable" is displayed. The following is the screenshot of the error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMfZL.png)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any missing values in there as those would get interpreted as `float` and would raise the `TypeError` on iterating?

Comment: Also, as Python deeply depends on indentation, please format your code to to match with the original so we understand your code better.

Comment: @Nickil Yes I do have a few fields which have null values. Could you please let me know how the missing or null values can be handled? How shall I format my data to handle missing or null values?

Comment: It depends on your usage. Do you want to drop them and compute the rest or you want to fill them using some techniques like `bfill/ffill`, mean/median, `imputer`. You must take the final call.

Comment: @Nickil I handled all the missing values and tried to re run the program, however it still shows the same error.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem, it turns out to be caused by the `NAN` in the first line. Please checks this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40223208/5318060