# checking string presence in list gives TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable

Tags: python, typeerror, information-retrieval, pagerank

I am running into a TypeError when checking a strings' presence in a list:

I checked similar issues such as the one in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49998463/how-to-solve-typeerror-float-object-is-not-iterable) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39238057/typeerror-argument-of-type-float-is-not-iterable) but i couldn't find a solution there.

I expect the code to calculate (one iteration of) the [page rank](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/af3909afbed9793d94f41bf99ec98d75d5f1335a) of all documents inside `"pagerank.txt`, which looks like this [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSDeV.png), but it runs into an error.

My full code:

```
def calc_pageranks(pagerank_file = "pagerank.txt", damping=0.9):
    pagerankScores = {}
    pagerankData = {} #dict of what files a file (the dict key) points to 
    with open(pagerank_file, "r") as f:
        for row in f:
            row = row.split()
            pagerankScores.update({row[0]:1}) #set starting pagerank for documents
            if len(row) == 1:
                pagerankData.update({row[0]:None})
            else:
                pagerankData.update({row[0]:row[1:]}) #pagerank graph
        for docName in pagerankData:
            pagerank = pagerankScores[docName]
            temp = 0
            for val in pagerankData.values():
                if val == None:
                    pass
                else:
                    if docName in val:
                        temp += pagerank / len(val)
                pagerank = (1 - damping) + damping * temp
                pagerankData.update({docName:pagerank})

    return pagerankScores, pagerankData
```

`docName` and `val` look like this:
`doc1.txt <class 'str'> ['doc2.txt', 'doc8.txt'] <class 'list'>`

Full error message:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3 /Users/MacSuperior/Desktop/Coding/IR_system/search_engine.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MacSuperior/Desktop/Coding/IR_system/search_engine.py", line 99, in <module>
    print(calc_pageranks())
  File "/Users/MacSuperior/Desktop/Coding/IR_system/search_engine.py", line 92, in calc_pageranks
    if docName in val:
TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable
```

Pagerank.txt:

```
doc1.txt doc2.txt doc8.txt
doc2.txt doc1.txt doc2.txt doc9.txt
doc3.txt doc4.txt
doc4.txt  doc1.txt doc10.txt
doc5.txt doc6.txt
doc6.txt
doc7.txt doc1.txt
doc8.txt doc9.txt doc10.txt
doc9.txt doc10.txt
doc10.txt doc9.txt
```

Comment: You are assuming that `val` is a string (or at least a sequence); don't do that.

Comment: @chepner can you explain further? I am assuming `val` is a list in which a string presence can be checked using `in`
edit: fixed it by inserting `if type(val) == list:` before checking if `docName` was in `val`

Comment: `pagerankData.update({docName:pagerank})` is adding the pagerank score to `pagerankData`'s values, so the you can't assume that all values in that dictionary are strings

Comment: I'm guessing that is a typo, and you meant `pagerankScores.update({docName:pagerank})`

Comment: Yes, it is another bug in my code: I accidentally updates `pagerankData` where it should have been `pagerankScores`, thank you @bn_ln

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of ideas to refactor to help eliminate typos.

```
def calc_pageranks(pagerank_file = "pagerank.txt", damping=0.9):
    pagerankScores = {}
    pagerankData = {} 
    
    with open(pagerank_file, "r") as f:
        for row in f:
            key, *values = row.split()
            pagerankData[key]  = values
        
        for docName in pagerankData:
            pagerank = (1-damping) + damping * sum((docName in value)/len(value) for value in pagerankData.values() if value)
            pagerankScores[docName] = pagerank
    
    return pagerankScores, pagerankData
```